# Is this matrix invertible?

Tags: matrix-inverse, partition-of-unity

- Suppose that $P$ is a finite partition of the unit $d$-dimensional hypercube composed of $m$ hyperrectangles $R_1,...,R_m$
- Denote $u_1,...,u_m$ the middle-point of each hyperrectangle : $u_i = \frac{b_i-a_i}{2}$ for $R_i = \times_{j=1}^{d} [a_{i,j},b_{i,j}]$
- For a given dimension $j \in 1,...,d$, define the matrix $E^{(j)}$ of size $m\times m$ by :

$$E_{k,l}^{(j)} = \frac{\lambda([0,u_{k,j}] \cap R_{l,j}])}{\lambda(R_{l,j})}$$

where $u_{k,j}$ denotes the $j$th coordinate of $u_k$ and $R_{l,j} = [a_{l,j},b_{l,j}]$ denotes the projection of $R_l$ onto the dimension $j$.

**Questions** :

1° What can you say about the space $ S^{(j)} = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m : E^{(j)}x = u_{.,j}\right\}$ ?

2° Are the matrices $E^{(j)}$ invertible ?

3° What about $S = \cap_{j=1}^m S^{(j)}$ ?

I started by trying to understand the structure of the matrices $E^{(j)}$. I understand that their diagonals are $1/2$, that all their values are between 0 and 1, but I can't say much about the off-diagonal terms. I guess that a majority of values will be either 0 or 1.

How can I get e.g. information about the kernel of such matrices ? This will give me a base of the affine subspace.